# One to Many relationship does not retrieve all item from list that was saved

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I have a one-to-many relationship with many ResourceTags per ResourceRequest in an MVC project.

Below is how I scaffolded the relationship with get and add methods. The add method successfully saves all the ResourceTags to the table.

However, upon retrieving the ResourceRequest as a list I only get one tag in the ICollection and it's usually a random tag i.e, not the latest one I added.

I have at least a dozen tags saved to the table for one row of ResourceRequest which I can see get updated on studio manager with the tag. However, only 1 tag gets retrieved using the GetResources() method for some reason. Any tips on why that is and how I can get it to update immediately and correctly with all the tags I added to the Resources tags collection?

```
public class ResourceTags
{

    [Key]
    public byte[] ResourceId { get; set; }

    public string Tag { get; set; }

    public ResourceRequest ResourceRequest { get; set; }
}



public class ResourceRequest
{
 
    [Key]
    public byte[] ID { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ResourceTags> ResourceTags { get; set; }

}



public DbSet<ResourceRequest>? Resources { get; set; }
public DbSet<ResourceTags>? ResourceTags { get; set; }

modelBuilder?.Entity<ResourceRequest>().ToTable("Resources");
modelBuilder?.Entity<ResourceTags>().ToTable("ResourceTags")
.HasOne<ResourceRequest>(rq => rq.ResourceRequest)
        .WithMany(rt => rt.ResourceTags)
        .HasForeignKey(id => id.ResourceId);


public void AddResourceTags(string id, string tagText)
{
  using var context = this.prismContext;

        byte[] convertedId = Convert.FromBase64String(id);
        var resource = context.Resources?.Find(convertedId);

        if (resource != null)
        {
            var tag = new ResourceTags { ResourceId = convertedId, Tag = tagText };
            context.ResourceTags?.Add(tag);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

    }


  public IEnumerable<ResourceRequest> GetResources()
    {
        var context = this.prismContext;
        var result = context.Resources?.Include(t => t.ResourceTags).Take(3);
        return result ?? Enumerable.Empty<ResourceRequest>();
    }
```

Comment: What does `this.prismContext` do? I.e. what is its code?

Comment: private readonly PrismContext prismContext; is the injected datacontext file in the constructor of the repository. I create a new instance context for each method.  var context = this.prismContext;

Comment: Hmm, it has to be something related to `byte[]` PK/FK. I've never seen usage of such type of key, and since `byte[]` is a reference type, I doubt the client side comparison used by materializing included related data works correctly (it probably uses compare by reference). What exactly is in these `byte[]`, can't it be changed to `Guid`?

Comment: No it cant really, I am getting a list of the correct relationship and a list of resourcetags but only one for each row. So something with the data in vs studio debugging not up to date with the table in sql serv. studio manager.

Comment: My bad, I forgot that "row version" fields are using `byte[]`, so EFC must have support for it. Also missed the `HasForeignKey` with PK property. @Steve Py answer is correctly explaining the cause of the issue.

Comment: Side note: you shouldn't use `using` in `AddResourceTags`. When a class has disposable members the class itself should dispose it. It's not expected that a method call dispose it. A subsequent method call (if it happens) will encounter a disposed context.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is likely with how you have your Keys defined. I'm somewhat surprised that EF didn't raise an alarm about it.

```
public class ResourceTags
{

    [Key]
    public byte[] ResourceId { get; set; }
```

Here you say ResourceTag has a PK called ResourceId, yet...

```
 modelBuilder?.Entity<ResourceTags>().ToTable("ResourceTags")
    .HasOne<ResourceRequest>(rq => rq.ResourceRequest)
    .WithMany(rt => rt.ResourceTags)
    .HasForeignKey(id => id.ResourceId);
```

Here you are saying the ResourceTag will map to it's ResourceRequest using the ResourceId column.

This is not a One-to-Many, this becomes a One-to-One as both tables are sharing the same PK since the FK to ResourceRequest is marked as the PK of ResourceTag.

What you probably should have is:

```
public class ResourceTags
{

    [Key]
    public byte[] ResourceTagId { get; set; }

    public byte[] ResourceId { get; set; } // <- FK to ResourceRequest
```

You can manage your basic mappings via attributes to remove the need for the modelBuilder configuration for the relationship:

```
public class ResourceTags
{

    [Key]
    public byte[] ResourceTagId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ResourceRequest))]
    public byte[] ResourceId { get; set; }

    public string Tag { get; set; }

    public ResourceRequest ResourceRequest { get; set; }
}
```

EF will auto-wire the Collection on the other end. (ResourceRequest.ResourceTags) Attributes can work for pretty much any general entity configuration which saves the bulk of messy configuration, where you would only have to add configuration statements for relationships that aren't clearly available via attributes.

Edit: If ResourceTags is a composite PK, EF can handle that but both fields need to be marked as the Key with a Column order:

public class ResourceTags
{

```
[Key, Column(Order=0), ForeignKey(nameof(ResourceRequest))]
public byte[] ResourceId { get; set; }

[Key, Column(Order=1)]
public string Tag { get; set; }

public ResourceRequest ResourceRequest { get; set; }
```

}

I believe that should get EF behaving more expectedly.

Comment: Thanks alot for taking a look at this problem. FYI: Theres a FK applied to ResourceID with a relationship to ID in Resources already set up. The resourcetags table is a composite key table i.e Tag and ResourceID are both keys? I currently get invalid column ResourceRequestID when I implement this solution. I should prob mentioned the table earlier. What would the ideal way of managing a one-to-many where the many table is composite key table?

Comment: That should be possible, I have updated the answer to include a composite key for the Tag which should work out better. ... Ah, I see below you had figured that out in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

So I was missing a composite key declaration to begin with and also I needed to implement your solution as above and tell SQL the order of the columns.

```
    public class ResourceTags
{


    [ForeignKey(nameof(ResourceRequest))]
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public byte[] ResourceId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Tag { get; set; }


    public ResourceRequest ResourceRequest { get; set; }
}

   modelBuilder?.Entity<ResourceTags>().ToTable("ResourceTags").HasKey(c => new { c.ResourceId, c.Tag });

        modelBuilder?.Entity<ResourceTags>().ToTable("ResourceTags")
        .HasOne(rq => rq.ResourceRequest)
        .WithMany(rt => rt.ResourceTags)
        .HasForeignKey(id => id.ResourceId);

    public IEnumerable<ResourceRequest> GetResources()
    {
        var result = this.prismContext.Resources?.Include(t => t.ResourceTags).Take(1).ToList();
        return result ?? Enumerable.Empty<ResourceRequest>();
    }
```

Comment: GetResources() now returns all the related tags for each row of ResourceRequest. Instead of only returning one seemingly random item.